# WPF: How to equally distribute the available height among 2 expander controls in Grid without any Gray area

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a Floating SplitPane, in which there are 3 expanders. The first expander has max of 3 rows of controls (label and textboxes) to display and needs to be displayed without a scroll.

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="Root" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--  Variables Expander  -->
        <Expander x:Name="GeneralExpander" >
                <!-- Two labels and Textboxes -->
        </Expander>
        <Grid x:Name="ExpanderGrid" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Expander x:Name="ParamsExpander" Collapsed="OnParamsExpanderCollapsed" Expanded="OnParamsExpanderExpanded" IsExpanded="False" >
                <view:ParamsView x:Name="ParamsView" />
            </Expander>
            <Expander x:Name="VariablesExpander" Grid.Row="1" Collapsed="OnVarsExpanderCollapsed" Expanded="OnVarsExpanderExpanded" IsExpanded="true">
                <view:VarsView x:Name="VarsView" />
            </Expander>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And second and third expanders have one DataGrid each and the number of rows depends on filters available in the Pane. For example: there is Favorites button at the Pane level, clicking on this button will show only favorite marked rows in the dataGrid and thus, it may have less number of rows.

My requirement is to, equally distribute the available space between 2nd and 3rd expanders (when in expanded state). For which I have below events in code-behind.

```
private void OnParamsExpanderExpanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.paramLoadRequired)
    {
        this.paramLoadRequired = false;
        // Populate respective datagrid rows
    }

    if (VarExpander.IsExpanded)
    {
        // Expander Grid rows (Params and Vars expanders) with equal height
        ExpanderGrid.RowDefinitions[0].Height = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Star);
        ExpanderGrid.RowDefinitions[1].Height = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Star);
        return;
    }

    ExpanderGrid.RowDefinitions[0].Height = GetStarGridLength();
    ExpanderGrid.RowDefinitions[1].Height = GetAutoGridLength();
}

private void OnVarsExpanderExpanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ParamsExpander.IsExpanded)
    {
        // Expander Grid rows (Params and Vars expanders) with equal height
        ExpanderGrid.RowDefinitions[0].Height = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Star);
        ExpanderGrid.RowDefinitions[1].Height = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Star);
        return;
    }

    ExpanderGrid.RowDefinitions[1].Height = GetStarGridLength();
    ExpanderGrid.RowDefinitions[0].Height = GetAutoGridLength();
}

private void OnVarsExpanderCollapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // When Vars collapsed, need to adjust the height of Params expander to occupy full available height
}

private void OnParamsExpanderCollapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // When Params collapsed, need to adjust the height of Vars expander to occupy full available height
}
```

Please see below screenshot on how it is behaving currently:
[Attached Image showing Current behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Phj.png)

**QUESTION:** But when I click on "Favorites" Star button, if any of them need only less height to display datagrid; the other expander needs to occupy the empty space instead of showing grey area.

Please give me some idea on how to achieve this (either from XAML or code-behind) and let me know if any other details required! Thanks in Advance.